# What's wrong with inputting a list inside a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

beginner here, I have a question about some code:

```
def flatten_list(lst):
  FinalList = []
  if lst == []:
    return []
  else:
    for x in len(lst):
      if isinstance(lst(x), list) == False:
        FinalList += lst(x)
      else: 
        s = lst(x)
        return FinalList += flatten_list(s)
```

At the very last line, there is an invalid syntax error, but I can't figure out why.
Any advice for this specific problem or general advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: what means `return FinalList += flatten_list(s)`

Comment: You could just `return FinalList + flatten_list(s)` without the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

`+=` must be its own statement, but you're trying to use it as an expression. It doesn't return anything so Python doesn't let you `return` it. If you want it to work the same as other languages, you need to use two statements:

```
FinalList += flatten_list(s)
return FinalList
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to write some code to flat a 2D list into a 1D list. Whenever the item is a list, you want to extend final list with elements of item list so that's why you're using `+=` operator (I guess). Here's sample code to achieve what I think you want to achieve ;)

```py
def flatten_list(lst):
    final_list = []
    if lst == []:
        return []
    else:
        for x in range(len(lst)):
            if isinstance(lst[x], list) == False:
                final_list.append(lst[x])
            else: # If it's a list
                # final_list.extend(lst[x]) # This will also work
                final_list += lst[x]
    return final_list

print(flatten_list([[1,2],3,[4,5,6],7.5,'Sample']))
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7.5, 'Sample']
```

Comment: `for x in lst` and changing all `lst[x]` to `x` would be even cleaner. You could also drop the first `else:` and remove one level of indentation for the code contained in it since the `if lst == []: return []` exits early.